# How can I use a variable to change a Database entry

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am very new to Laravel and I don't quite know what to search in order to get a good result, please forgive me if there are many like this, I really don't know what to search, but I have tried.

In Laravel I basically have 8 links in my View, each one of them is routed to the same Controller and URL.

What I want to achieve is, for each one of the links that are clicks, a single controller needs to know what link has been clicked... I have already achieved this by using separate controllers, but when I realised that I needed to change something on every single controller, I realised this can't be how Laravel, or even PHP is supposed to be used for optimal performance.

So in my View I have 8 of these...

```
{{ '<p class="green"><A href="#">Default Notice</A></p>' }}
```

All with different text between the  tag, and I want a single controller to be able to know which button has been pressed, in order to update 1 of 8  columns in a database that corresponds to the link clicked.

I have the database model set up, that is not the problem. The problem is being able to determine which of the links has been clicked, in a single controller so I can then go ahead and say...

```
if($link == 'a certain name'){
    $model->acolumnname = 1;
}
```

I hope I have explained myself??
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use plain ol' query strings? (if you don't want to pass a parameter)

(btw, why using blade when writing out simple html??)

```
<p class="green"><A href="{{url('/?link=1')}}">Default Notice</A></p>
<p class="green"><A href="{{url('/?link=2')}}">Default Notice</A></p>
<p class="green"><A href="{{url('/?link=3')}}">Default Notice</A></p>
```

Say you have this route:

```
Route::get('/', 'MyController@method');
```

In your MyController class:

```
public function method()
{
  # if not present, defaults to `null`, or pass a second paramenter to make 
  # it the default one
  $link = Request::query('link');
  if($link){  
    $model->acolumnname = $link;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go along with other answerers'. I am using blade to write out the HTML as it is part of an if statement in blade ;)

Comment: @user3542280 still you can go without using blade: `@if($whatever) <p>Regular html</p> @endif`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a single `Controller`  like this:

```
class PageController extends BaseControlle {

    public function page($page = null)
    {
        if(!is_null($page)) {
            // Page Model
            $data = Page::where('slug', $page)->get();
            return View::make('page')->with('data', $data);
        }
    }

}
```

In your `routes.php` file you may add this route:

```
Route::get('page/{slug}', array('uses' => 'PageController@page', 'as' => 'page.show'));
```

To generate links for your pages you may try something like this in your `view`:

```
<a href = "{{ route('page.show', array('slug' => 'home')) }}">Home</a>
<a href = "{{ route('page.show', array('slug' => 'about')) }}">About</a>
// More...
```